# Applying background to lists

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a ul list, which is formed as a table format. table format in the sense if i put 15 words in the single cell table-row will extend but not in ul list format. but i have done as like table format in the ul list.

My problem is

if i apply background for single cell that will apply beneath cell too. I need that particular has background color:

Here jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/thilakar/TewjZ/

Comment: This might not work in your actual code (because of background imaging or gradients), but how about giving everything a white background instead of transparant?

Comment: you can apply solid color for li. that affect the beneath cell too. no need to apply background image or gradients

Comment: nanba i don't know what you need. easy to try use table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try,

```
.today {background:#ccc; margin:0 !important; padding:0!important}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you seem to be setting some bad CSS property values.

The corrected code: http://jsfiddle.net/nayish/TewjZ/1/

The problem does not apear here. What I've changed is the `margin-bottom: -300px` and the `padding-bottom: 308px` you had set.

The main problem was that each table-cell was actually higher than it seemed and stretched beneath the other table cell's below it.

Comment: sorry nayish, i need a solution with the margin-bottom:-300px and padding-bottom:308px;

Comment: Can you explain better why you need this? any solution that would be given keeping these would cause you much problem in the future since the table-cells are actually not as they appear and are actually clashing behind each other causing the painting of one to paint the rest. A solution of painting all table-cells white will cause your borders to disappear, if you are interested in this type of solution check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/nayish/TewjZ/3/